# save answer in Prolog using tell function

Tags: prolog

i am doing a Prolog project and below is my code.

```
:- dynamic yes/1,no/1.
:- dynamic n_angle/1.

go :- hypothesize(Shape),
  write('Yes I know the shape you talking about is a '),
  write(Shape),
  write('!!!!'),
  undo.

hypothesize(circle)          :- circle,!.

circle :- not(verify(width)),
      verify(radius),
      not(verify(height)),
      verify(diameter_equal_2_radius).

ask(Question):-

write('Has the shape '),
write(Question),
write('?'),
read(Response),
nl,
((Response == yes ; Response == y)
  -> assert(yes(Question));
     assert(no(Question)), fail).

verify(S) :-
   (yes(S) ->  true ;
   (no(S)  ->  fail ;
   ask(S))).

save_file:- tell('D:ansSave.txt').

/* undo all yes/no assertions */
undo :- retract(yes(_)),fail.
undo :- retract(no(_)),fail.
undo :- retract(n_angle(_)),fail.
undo.
```

and the result will be like this.

?- go.
Has the shape width?n.

Has the shape radius?y.

Has the shape height?n.

Has the shape diameter_equal_2_radius?y.

Yes I know the shape you talking about is a circle!!!!

true.

i want to save the result as shown above to a txt file.

but when i try to put the save_file to the ask function

```
ask(Question):-
 save_file,
write('Has the shape '),
write(Question),
write('?'),
read(Response),
nl,
told,
((Response == yes ; Response == y)
  -> assert(yes(Question));
     assert(no(Question)), fail).
```

it will overwrite the result every time.  can anyone tell me how to solve this ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Overwriting the result or overwriting previous results?

Comment: it will overwrite the previous data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to overwrite previous file content, consider using `append/1`.

So your rule must be:

```
save_file:- append('D:ansSave.txt').
```

Comment: but how am i apply the save_file in side the program. i am quite confused in this . can u help me to point out ? if i want to save the data as shown as above.

Comment: I can't seem to start running a querry. Could you write a test case that runs in your machine, not a test case given to you?

Comment: `go.` returns `false` immediately